# x:Bind a Vector3 Object in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp-xaml

I have created a vector3 Object for the `StackPanel` translation. How can bind this value directly to the StackPanel in xaml? Any Ideas?
The vector3 Object is

```cs
var elevation = new Vector3(0, 0, 18);
```

Comment: Could you please share more code about what you are trying to do?

Comment: there you go `<StackPanel
                Margin="0 30 0 30"
                x:Name="TestPanel"
                Background="Red"
                Height="60"
                Width="200"
                Translation="{x:Bind ShadowVector}">
                <StackPanel.Shadow>
                    <ThemeShadow/>
                </StackPanel.Shadow>
            </StackPanel>` now how to do it all i xaml without referencing it from code behind

Answer (score 1):

```
            <StackPanel
            Margin="0 30 0 30"
            x:Name="TestPanel"
            Background="Red"
            Height="60"
            Width="200"
            Translation="0,0,20">
            <StackPanel.Shadow>
                <ThemeShadow/>
            </StackPanel.Shadow>
        </StackPanel>
```